# Why is the return value of an empty python regexp search a match?

Tags: python, regex

When passing an empty string to a regular expression object, the result of a search is a match object an not None. Should it be None since there is nothing to match?

```
import re

m = re.search("", "some text")
if m is None:
    print "Returned None"
else:
    print "Return a match"
```

Incidentally, using the special symbols `^` and `$` yield the same result.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Empty pattern matches any part of the string.

Check this:

```
import re

re.search("", "ffff")
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0xb7166410>

re.search("", "ffff").start()
0

re.search("$", "ffff").start()
4
```

Adding $ doesn't yield the same result. Match is at the end, because it is the only place it can be.

Comment: if no matches are found, what does it return? Some falsy value like `None` or does it throw an exception?! [nevermind, found my answer in the documentation.](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search)

Answer (score 3):

Look at it this way: Everything you searched for was matched, therefore the search was successful and you get a match object.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to be doing is not checking if m is None, rather you want to check if m is True:

```
if m:
    print "Found a match"
else:
    print "No match"
```

Also, the empty pattern matches the whole string.

Comment: If m is `None` then `bool(m)` is `False`. He should check, whether `m` is `None`.

Comment: @gruszczy that doesn't say if there's a match, though

Comment: In [5]: bool(re.search("", "ffff"))
Out[5]: True

In [6]: bool(re.search("$", "ffff"))
Out[6]: True

Comment: 1.) an empty pattern matches anything, 2.) `bool(re.match('$', 'ffff'))` returns False. The searching behavior must be some regexp quirk

Comment: Of course it returns False, because `re.match('$', 'ffff')` returned None, which gives False when coerced to bool.

Answer (score 1):

Those regular expressions are successfully matching 0 literal characters.

All strings can be thought of as containing an infinite number of empty strings between the characters:

```
'Foo' = '' + '' + ... + 'F' + '' + ... + '' + 'oo' + '' + ...
```